# SQL query , group by only one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssrs-2012

i want to group this query by project only because there are two records of same project but i only want one.
But when i add group by clause it asks me to add other columns as well by which grouping does not work.

```
*

DECLARE @Year varchar(75) = '2018'
DECLARE @von DateTime = '1.09.2018'
DECLARE @bis DateTime = '30.09.2018'
select new_projekt ,new_geschftsartname, new_mitarbeitername, new_stundensatz
from Filterednew_projektkondition ps
left join Filterednew_fakturierungsplan fp on ps.new_projekt = fp.new_hauptprojekt1
where ps.statecodename = 'Aktiv'
  and fp.new_startdatum >= @von +'00:00:00' 
  and fp.new_enddatum <= @bis +'23:59:59'
  --and new_projekt= Filterednew_projekt.new_
--group by new_projekt
```

*

look at the column new_projekt . row 2 and 3 has same project, but i want it to appear only once. Due to different other columns this is not possible.
if its of interested , there is another coluim projectcondition id which is unique for both
[image: Result]

Comment: If a column isn't contained in the `GROUP BY` then it must be within an aggregate function. We can't run your query, as we don't have access to it; so can you elaborate more? Provide sample data and expected results.

Comment: The fp conditions in the WHERE clause turns the LEFT JOIN into an INNER JOIN. Move those conditions to the ON clause to get true LEFT JOIN result.

Comment: Use `GROUP BY` for aggregation, use `DISTINCT` to select unique records.

Comment: hi, look at the column new_projekt . row 2 and 3 has same project, but i want it to appear only once. Due to different other columns this is not possible.Do you understand the problem?

Comment: OK We understand your problem. Next question: you have two distinct values for new_ges... and new_stund... columns. WHICH ONE SHOULD WE DISPLAY WHEN THE TWO ROWS ARE MERGED?

Comment: i want the one with new_studensatz minimum value,  i.e the third row.

Comment: i tried the min() on all select coulumns unfortunately, new_geshaft value becomes inccorecct, because it take the minnimum of some alphabet.

Comment: Yeah, you can't do that, because the database throws all the values into a bucket, and pulls out the MIN of each value. It doesn't remember which row the values came from. You have to adopt a different strategy, something more like "number all the rows in ascending order of X and keep only the rows with a number 1" - see my answer, last paragraph, for more info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't ask a database to decide arbitrarily for you, which records should be thrown away when doing a group. You have to be precise and specific

Example, here is some data about a person:

```
Name, AddressZipCode
John Doe, 90210
John Doe, 12345
```

`SELECT name, addresszipcode FROM person INNER JOIN address on address.personid = person.id`

There are two addresses stored for this one guy, the person data is repeated in the output!

> "I don't want that. I only want to see one line for this guy, together with his address"

Which address?

That's what you have to tell the database

> "Well, obviously his current address"

And how do you denote that an address is current?

> "It's the one with the null enddate"

`SELECT name, addresszipcode FROM person INNER JOIN address on address.personid = person.id WHERE address.enddate = null`

If you still get two addresses out, there are two address records that are null - you have data that is in violation of your business data modelling principles ("a person's address history shall have at most one adddress that is current, denoted by a null end date") - fix the data

> "Why can't i just group by name?"

You can, but if you do, you still have to tell the database how to accumulate the non-name data that it shows you. You want an address data out of it, it has 2 it wants to show you, you have to tell it which to discard. You could do this:

`SELECT name, MAX(addresszipcode) FROM person INNER JOIN address on address.personid = person.id GROUP BY name`

> "But I don't want the max zipcode? That doesn't make sense"

OK, use the MIN, the SUM, the AVG, anything that makes sense. If none of these make sense, then use something that does, like the address line that has the highest end date, or the lowest end date that is a future end date. If you only want one address on show you must decide how to boil that data down to just one record - you have to write the rule for the database to follow and no question about it **you have to create a rule** so make it a rule that describes what you actually want

---

Ok, so you created a rule - you want only the rows with the minimum new_stundenstatz

```
DECLARE @Year varchar(75) = '2018'
DECLARE @von DateTime = '1.09.2018'
DECLARE @bis DateTime = '30.09.2018'
select new_projekt ,new_geschftsartname, new_mitarbeitername, new_stundensatz
from 

(SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITON BY new_projekt ORDER BY new_stundensatz) rown FROM Filterednew_projektkondition) ps

left join 
Filterednew_fakturierungsplan fp on ps.new_projekt = fp.new_hauptprojekt1 
where ps.statecodename = 'Aktiv'
  and fp.new_startdatum >= @von +'00:00:00' 
  and fp.new_enddatum <= @bis +'23:59:59'
  and ps.rown = 1
```

Here I've used an analytic operation to number the rows in your PS table. They're numbered in order of ascending `new_stundensatz`, starting with 1. The numbering restarts when the `new_projekt` changes, so each `new_projekt` will have a number 1 row.. and then we make that a condition of the where

(Helpful side note for applying this technique in future.. Ff it were the FP table we were adding a row number to, we would need to put `AND fp.rown= 1` in the ON clause, not the WHERE clause, because putting it in the where would make the LEFT join behave like an INNER, hiding rows that don't have any FP matching record)

Comment: Incorrect syntax near the OVER keyword. i fixed the partition spelling but still get the error?

Comment: also new:studensatz is in Filterednew_projektkondition table and not in Filterednew_fakturierungsplan

Comment: Row_Number is missing () it fixes the error but new_stundesatz is in other table. How can i fix this?

Comment: Fixed that up, sorry. Always a good idea to full qualify every column name (add all the missing PS. and FP. to the column names in your select list) as it can prevent queries stopping working after theyre added to a prodution system - if someone in future adds a column to the db that is the same name as an existing column in another table( e.g. someone adds new_studensatz to the fp table in future) then this query that uses both tables will suddenly have an ambiguous reference to the named column; this is why fully qualifying every column with its table alias is a good idea